# serializeArray() returning too many elements

Tags: jquery

Please see the image below, I needed `serializeArray()` to return one object and not 4 as the `length` property gave only one in the selection.

How can I get jQuery serializeArray() to just return all the elements which do not have the class `inactive` as stated in the image? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If requirement is to serialize a single element to an object within and array, you can create an array, and an object; set object property to `name` of element, set object value to `value` of element, push object to array.

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};
var props = $("form").not(".inactive");
obj[props.attr("name")] = props.val();
arr.push(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Not for one single element but for many that have there class is not set to `inactive`

Comment: _"Not for one single element but for many that have there class is not set to `inactive`"_? What do you mean? Can you include text of `html`  and expected result at Question? Do the elements that have the same `className`  have the same `name` attribute value?